# How to disable a component depending on ng-option value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table containing a dynamic number of tr corresponding to the items of a list.
For each row, I want to have a combobox filled with pre-determined codes, a date field (irrelevant) and a jurisdiction (text) field.

Depending on the code selected in the combobox, I want to disable the text field of the same row.

I've tried to add a new property dynamically for each item "jurisdictionDisabled" but for some reason it ended up coupling all the jurisdiction fields for each row (i.e : if the code selected in combobox of row 1 make the jurisdiction field disable, then the jurisdiction field of row 2,3,... will also be disable)

**edit_bulletin.xhtml**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>#{cjr_main.LegalRemedy} ({{bulletin.legalRemedies.length}})</legend>
    <!-- FR, NL, DE remarks-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="rf-dt-shdr-c">#{cjr_main.legalRemedyType}</th>
            <th class="rf-dt-shdr-c">#{cjr_main.legalRemedyDate}</th>
            <th class="rf-dt-shdr-c">#{cjr_main.legalRemedyJurisdiction}</th>
            <th class="rf-dt-shdr-c">#{cjr_main.legalRemedyRemark}</th>
            <th class="rf-dt-shdr-c"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="legalRemedy in bulletin.legalRemedies track by $index">
                <td>
                    <select
                        ng-model="selectedLegalRemedyTypeCode" 
                        ng-options="legalRemedyType.code as getLegalRemedyTypeBasedOnLocale(legalRemedyType) for legalRemedyType in globalLegalRemedyTypes"
                        ng-change="updateLegalRemedyFields(selectedLegalRemedyTypeCode,$index)">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" size="10" ng-model="legalRemedy.date" 
                    ui-mask="99/99/9999"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="10" 
                    ng-model="legalRemedy.jurisdiction" ng-disabled="currentLegalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="F N D [R]" ng-click="showLegalRemedyPopup(legalRemedy)" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a ng-click="removeLegalRemedy(legalRemedy, '#{cjr_main.confirmDeleteLegalRemedy}')">
                        <h:graphicImage value="#{UserInfoBean.imagesRelativePath}/delete.gif" alt="delete"/>
                    </a>
                </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br></br>
        <input type="button" id="addLegalRemedyButton" ng-click="addLegalRemedy()" value="#{cjr_main.addLegalRemedy}"/>
</fieldset>
```

**controller.js**

```
/** legal remedies **/

$scope.addLegalRemedy = function(){
    $scope.bulletin.addLegalRemedy($scope.defaultLegalRemedy);
    $scope.currentLegalRemedy = {};
}

$scope.removeLegalRemedy = function (legalRemedy, confirmationMsg){
    confirmModal(confirmationMsg, function(){
        $scope.bulletin.removeLegalRemedy(legalRemedy);
        $scope.$apply();
    })
}

$scope.getLegalRemedyTypeBasedOnLocale = function(legalRemedy){
    if(currentLocale.indexOf('nl') !== -1){
        return legalRemedy.dutchDescription;
    } else if(currentLocale.indexOf('de') !== -1){
        return legalRemedy.germanDescription;
    } else{
        return legalRemedy.frenchDescription;
    }
}


$scope.updateLegalRemedyFields = function(selectedLegalRemedyTypeCode, currentLegalRemedyIndex){
    $scope.currentLegalRemedy = $scope.bulletin.legalRemedies[currentLegalRemedyIndex];

    // Should update date field aswell but the rules show that it's always displayed for providden codes
    switch(selectedLegalRemedyTypeCode){
        case "OPPOSITION" : 
            $scope.currentLegalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled= true;
            break;
        case "APPEAL" : 
            $scope.currentLegalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled = false;
            break;
        case "CONFIRMED BY" :
            $scope.currentLegalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled = false;
            break;
        default :  $scope.currentLegalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable for EACH `select`, but here you have declared only 1. Attach a variable to each `legalRemedy` to hold the selected value for THAT item only:

```
<select
  ng-model="legalRemedy.selectedLegalRemedyTypeCode" 
  ng-options="legalRemedyType.code as getLegalRemedyTypeBasedOnLocale(legalRemedyType) for legalRemedyType in globalLegalRemedyTypes"
  ng-change="updateLegalRemedyFields(legalRemedy)">
</select>
```

You have also made it a little more complicated than it needs to be. Pass the current item to your function. The item itself stores the true/false value that determines whether or not to disable the input. You can think of the `legalRemedy` variable as the entire scope for that particular instance of `ng-repeat`:

```
<input type="text" size="10" 
  ng-model="legalRemedy.jurisdiction" 
  ng-disabled="legalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled"/>
```

There is no need to pass anything else, since you everything you need is attached to the item itself:

```
updateLegalRemedyFields(legalRemedy) {
  switch(legalRememdy.selectedLegalRemedyTypeCode) {
    case "OPPOSITION" : 
        legalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled= true;
        break;
    case "APPEAL" : 
        legalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled = false;
        break;
    case "CONFIRMED BY" :
        legalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled = false;
        break;
    default :  legalRemedy.jurisdictionDisabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've done things more complicated because I tried passing the current item at first but without success. I didn't think of `ng-model="legalRemedy.selectedLegalRemedyTypeCode"`, so that solved the problem, thanks for the info.
Unfortunately, now that the jurisdiction fields are working as they should, it's the combobox turn to be synchronized with each other (i.e. selecting "APPEAL" in 1 combobox will select it in the other rows as well)

Comment: So, you are saying you want all the combo boxes to be the same? So that, if you select "APPEAL" for one, they all will be set to "APPEAL"?

Comment: No, it's the situation as of right now with the changes, but obviously that's not the expected output

Comment: As long as that select is inside the `ngRepeat` that should not be the case. Double check the spelling of your `ngModel` definition for that select input

Comment: I've double checked but there's nothing wrong with my spelling...
I'm still investigating

Comment: For some reasons after some rebuild & deploy this eventually worked. I don't think I've changed anything really. Nevertheless, your answer solver my problem, thanks

Comment: I think it was when I add a new line to the table, I was calling `$scope.bulletin.addLegalRemedy($scope.defaultLegalRemedy);`
which I replaced with `$scope.bulletin.addLegalRemedy(angular.copy($scope.defaultLegalRemedy));` (defaultLegalRemedy is defined as such : `$scope.defaultLegalRemedy = {};`)